# Toggle button does not give action

Tags: laravel

I am update status of product using bootstrap toggle but cna not work. It can not give alert in my jquery function. what is mistake is done by me??
layout.blade.php My layout.blade.php file sequence of jquery is correct or not. I think problem is sequence of files imports in layout.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Ecommerce Website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />

<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<!-- bootstrap-css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" >
<!-- //bootstrap-css -->
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css')}}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="{{ asset('css/style-responsive.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- font CSS -->
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- font-awesome icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font.css')}}" type="text/css"/>
<link href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/morris.css')}}" type="text/css"/>
<!-- calendar -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/monthly.css')}}">
<!-- //calendar -->
<!-- alertify -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/alertify.min.css')}}">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.7/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- //font-awesome icons -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
               integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
               crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>


<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery2.0.3.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/raphael-min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/morris.js')}}"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/alertify.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      @if(session('success_category'))
          alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-center');
          alertify.success("{{session('success_category')}}");
      @endif
      @if(session('update_category'))
          alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-center');
          alertify.success("{{session('update_category')}}");
      @endif
      @if(session('success_subcategory'))
          alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-center');
          alertify.success("{{session('success_subcategory')}}");
      @endif
      @if(session('update_subcategory'))
          alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-center');
          alertify.success("{{session('update_subcategory')}}");
      @endif
      @if(session('success_product'))
          alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-center');
          alertify.success("{{session('success_product')}}");
      @endif
       @if(session('update_product'))
          alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-center');
          alertify.success("{{session('update_product')}}");
      @endif
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/scripts.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.slimscroll.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.nicescroll.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.scrollTo.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
        "scrollX": true,
    } );
 
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table );
} );
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js
"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.7/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js

"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js

"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js

"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
<!-- morris JavaScript -->  

</body>
</html>
```

blade:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
                   crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
        <input data-id="{{$item->product_id}}" id="toggle_class" class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" {{ $item->active_deactive_status ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

controller:

```
 public function activeDeactiveStatus(Request $request)
    {
          DB::table('products')
              ->where('product_id', $request->product_id)
              ->update(['active_deactive_status'=>$request->active_deactive_status]);

           return response()->json(['success'=>'product status change successfully.']);
    }
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toggle_class').change(function() {
        var active_deactive_status = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0; 
        var product_id = $(this).data('id'); 
         alert(active_deactive_status);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: '/changeStatus',
            data: {'active_deactive_status': active_deactive_status, 'product_id': product_id},
            success: function(data){
              console.log(data.success)
            }
        });
    })  


});
</script>
```

Comment: what is not working toggle ? or update function

Comment: toggle is not working??

Comment: @KamleshPaul code is working when i remove all toggle class from checbox and write code on click of checkbox but i want this functionality for toggle

Comment: put java script code outside of `ready()` and check

Comment: @KamleshPaul plz check layout.blade.php

Comment: your main blade don't have input

Comment: @KamleshPaul its separte file and it include in another file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226081/discussion-between-kamlesh-paul-and-seema-patil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is working here

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#toggle_class').click(function () {
      var active_deactive_status = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0;
      var product_id = $(this).data('id');
      alert(active_deactive_status);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    


  <input data-id="12" id="toggle_class" class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" >
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can i share my layout .blade.php

Comment: @seemapatil great